# javascript e7 async await return

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await, return

I am new to async/await in javascript. In the following code, I have an async function with a jquery ajax call that resolves. However, when I return the *cart* variable and set it to *arr*, I get an undefined value in console that shows up first, which means that console.log(arr) is firing before. How do I return this value into *arr*, and work on that variable?

```
async function what(http) {
  let d = await $.ajax({
    url: http,
    method: "GET"
  });
  console.log(d); ///this outputs the resolved promise.
  console.log(d.results); //as does this.

  let cart = await d.results;
  console.log("cart " + cart[0]); //as does this
  return cart; //this returns as undefined.
}
var arr = what(http);
console.log(arr); //this returns as undefined.
```

I feel like I should be able to return the value out of the function and then continue with my code.

Comment: `what(http).then ( arr => console.log(arr) );` -- need  to treat as promise.

Comment: No, `arr` definitely does not show up as `undefined`. It's a promise.

Comment: What do you mean by "*outputs the resolved promise.*"? It should output the *result* of the fulfilled promise, not the promise itself. You might want to post a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: I've created a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/55unkqLd/) based on your example, replacing $.ajax calls with synthetic promise. It clearly shows that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Bergi console.log(d) shows the data, but console.log(arr) doesn't. I return *cart* which should be the data from *d*. Why does returning cart and setting arr gives me an undefined value?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I fail to see the problem here; updated [**the demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/z9mm8kq5/) to include timestamps in logged messages. Yes, `console.log(arr)` will be executed first - as you don't _await_ for the result of `what()`, making the code execution synchronous. Inside `what`, however, all console.log calls are executed after Promise is resolved.

Comment: Is it correct for me to assume that there is no way to return the value, but only the promise? raina77ow's demo and Bergi's comments deal with a return that is a promise.

Comment: @BilalTahir Yes, that's correct. You cannot return the value from the future.

Comment: You need to either use `await` (only possible inside async function; one way out is wrapping the whole code into async IIFE, like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ydjo2zs/), or going back to traditional syntax mentioned in the very first comment here. )

Comment: OK, thanks! the timestamp helped! I guess I need to get the data from the promise which is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: http,
    method: "GET"
  }).promise()
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't used await unless you wrap it in a async function.

```
// ... your code
const main = async function() {
 // put the main body of your code here
 const arr = await what(http);
 console.log(arr)
}

main()
```

Here is an article you should read about using async / await with jQuery

http://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax/